# how to setup rest api client in codeigniter ,spark and curl are not working,how to get data with basic aut in rest api

Tags: php, rest, api, codeigniter, rest-client

Please help me to setup rest API client in Codeigniter, i did setup but its showing error of spark and curl, i searched in the internet ,got to know that spark and curl are not using now a days , so how to get a rest API (basic-authentication) data

```
$this->load->spark('restclient/2.1.0');
// Load the library
$this->load->library('rest');
// Run some setup
$this->rest->initialize(array('server' => 'http://api.twitter.com/'));
// Pull in an array of tweets
$tweets = $this->rest->get('1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=jenksuy&count=2');
$tweetobjects = json_decode($tweets);
foreach ($tweetobjects['results'] as $tweet) {
    log_message('info', $tweet['text']);
}
```

Comment: I assume best is to use Guzzle:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40026107

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Another vote for Guzzle.